# Can the user change the React/React Native state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express

I am currently working on a React Native app and I was wondering if the current logged in user can change anything stored in the state. Also, I have the same question but for a React website.

I am storing a user attribute `subbed: boolean` coming from my ExpressJS api and I don't want the user to be able to change it because some functionalities are for subbed only.

I am also using JWT sent on every request but I don't know if I am misunderstanding something or not.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is a programmer, and they care enough, and they're on a platform sophisticated enough to allow messing with the code or network payloads (for example, on a computer, but probably not a phone), yes, they could in theory change whatever they wanted to.

A good assumption to make is that the client can modify the code and run it *any way they want*. There's no stopping this - if the client runs the code, the client has to be sent the code, and if the client is sent the code, the client could also intercept the code and modify it if they were motivated enough. The only way to prevent a certain client from doing something they don't have permissions to do with some sort of data is to *not send them the data in the first place*. For example, if you have a video website and only certain users are permitted to see the subtitles, the only (mostly) trustworthy way of making sure that only authorized users can use the subtitles would be to only send the subtitles when the server has authorized that user's credentials.

That said, client-side tampering is quite uncommon and requires at least a moderate amount of skill and effort on the user's part. The vast majority of users are not programmers, after all. Unless serving the data is a security risk, you may well consider it to be not worth worrying about.

Ways to partially mitigate this without changing the program's structure are to:

- Obfuscate and minify the script the client uses. If a script is large and minified, it may be extremely difficult for someone reading it to understand and tweak.
- Encode the network payloads somehow - not just through HTTPS, but in a way that a programmer examining it on the client-side can't easily understand what data was sent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what would be a good alternative to show data only if the user is subbed? Should I do something server-side and only return data if the attribute is set to true?

Comment: That's the general idea. If serving the data is a security risk, definitely. If implementing the change is easy, go for it if you want. If it wouldn't be an easy tweak and it wouldn't be a security risk, I wouldn't bother, unless your site happens to be widely used and these sorts of potentially illegitimate users make up a not-insignificant number. Lots of sites don't bother, so if you don't think it's worth it, that's a perfectly acceptable conclusion.

Comment: I think not doing it would leave a back door open for anyone with knowledge to bypass the subscription system and have access to non-free content. Dealing with which data is being sent server-side shouldn't be too hard to implement. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :)